# Query error, column ambiguos

Tags: sql

The query produces an error message. Why is this the case? What may be done to correct the query?

```
SELECT NAME, DATE
FROM LETTER, LANGUAGE, CITY
WHERE LANGUAGE = LANG_ID
AND PLACE_SENT = CITY_ID ;
```

Error:

> Query could not be executed : 1052: Column 'LANGUAGE' in where clause
>   is ambiguous

Comment: post your error message as well

Comment: what is the error message? and which database are you running this query on?

Comment: Query could not be executed : 
1052: Column 'LANGUAGE' in where clause is ambiguous

Comment: http://www.bookandbyte.org/DMT/Exercises/SQL/Sijthoff_SQL.txt

Comment: Can you describe the table schema for these tables - LETTER, LANGUAGE, CITY. It seems that LANGAUAGE column is present in more than one table..

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago!) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

**1st :** It means `LANGUAGE` column presented in both tables .You need to specify which one you want to get.

**2nd :** you need to use `table` name with `column name` to avoid column name `ambiguous` `error`

```
SELECT LETTER.NAME, LETTER.DATE
FROM LETTER , LANGUAGE, CITY
WHERE LETTER.LANGUAGE = LANGUAGE.LANG_ID
AND LETTER.PLACE_SENT = CITY.CITY_ID ;
```

Answer (score 0):

So the LANGUAUGE column is present in more then one table . Hence you need to clarify which table you want to pick this column from.. Please add table name also in the `where` clause

```
SELECT LETTER.NAME, LETTER.DATE
FROM LETTER , LANGUAGE, CITY
WHERE LETTER.LANGUAGE = LANGUAGE.LANG_ID
AND LETTER.PLACE_SENT = CITY.CITY_ID ;
```

Answer (score 0):

As I have to guess:

```
SELECT NAME, DATE
FROM LETTER, LANGUAGE, CITY
WHERE LETTER.LANGUAGE = LANG_ID
AND PLACE_SENT = CITY_ID ;
```

or

```
SELECT NAME, DATE
FROM LETTER, LANGUAGE, CITY
WHERE CITY.LANGUAGE = LANG_ID
AND PLACE_SENT = CITY_ID ;
```

or

```
SELECT NAME, DATE
FROM LETTER, LANGUAGE, CITY
WHERE LANGUAGE.LANGUAGE = LANG_ID
AND PLACE_SENT = CITY_ID ;
```

or

```
SELECT NAME, DATE
FROM LETTER, LANGUAGE, CITY
WHERE LANGUAGE.ID = LANG_ID
AND PLACE_SENT = CITY_ID ;
```

may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is table with name LANGUAGE and also an Attribute name is LANGUAGE.
i have marked them both with Bold text in your query. Also do mention the where clause as **TABLE.Attribute**
look below

SELECT NAME, DATE
FROM LETTER, **LANGUAGE**, CITY
WHERE ***Table.*** **LANGUAGE** = LANG_ID
AND ***Table.*** PLACE_SENT = CITY_ID ;